# What is the other parameter in changeMood function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn React and came across this code on the website: https://www.reactenlightenment.com/react-state/8.2.html

I understood what the code does but could not understand what is parameter **'a'** in changeMood function. I ran the code after removing it and code worked well.

```
var MoodComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {mood: ':|'};
  },
  changeMood:function(event, a){
    const moods = [':)',':|',':('];
    const current = moods.indexOf(event.target.textContent);
    this.setState({mood: current === 2 ? moods[0] : moods[current+1]});
  },
  render: function() {
      return (
        <span style={{fontSize:'60',border:'1px solid #333',cursor:'pointer'}} 
              onClick={this.changeMood}>
              {this.state.mood}
        </span>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything.

The `onClick` only sends 1 parameter, the `event`, which is a Synthetic event created by React to handle cross browser compatibility.

For more info, check the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) on handling events

Comment: Is it a typing error that it was included in the code?

Comment: I believe so, because it isn't used in that scope